# NVIDIA driver won't recongize Asus Gefore GTX520 video card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, pci-express, nvidia-graphics-card

I want to replace my working video card that is in my system, which is Nvidia Gefore 9800, with Asus Geforce GTX520 video card on my Windows 7 64 bit. For some odd reason, no matter what I do the system won't recognize the video card even connected to the PCIE slot. I downloaded the driver from Asus website. The drivers are basically Nvidia drivers. Then, I installed and ran it. The first thing that comes up is that it can't find any Nvidia hardware and then the installer shuts down. I try to do this with the Asus GTX520 in the PCI slot through on board VGA output, because none of the output on the Asus video card works. However, when I do run Ubuntu Linux, Asus GTX520 does work just not on Windows 7. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Any GTX520 board should work straight away with NVidia's own drivers, which are updated very frequently. It doesn't matter that your card is an Asus card, stick to Nvidia's drivers. If the card is not detected by the installer you're using then you have a driver installer that's badly written and is not detecting the card properly: switch to Nvidia's drivers.

Comment: It's clearly not b or c, as it works in Linux.